# How to run user interactive c program with php

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I want to run the c program with php. I ran with `exec` and `passthru`. I make this running through gcc command line inside PHP script. But the problem is,  when I am using an interactive `C` program , At this situation my script runs long time and not finishing and not able to do anything with that port number on which the script is try to run for the  user input `C` program.

Here is some lines of the code:

```
$b='C:\Users\anil\Desktop\a.out';    
echo passthru($b);
```

This script runs if c program is without user input, but if the c program will be with user input then script continues running and create the problem as said above.

Now For the user interactive program ,  I want to show the user timeout message or There could be something to pass the user input at runtime or someway to pass the user input.

I used `set_time_limit()` ,but still script continues to show the timeout & Also not able to find the passing the way of user input.

May you please help me out at this point, Thanking you in Advance.

Comment: The function you're looking for is `proc_open`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This all looks like a _really_ bad idea.

Comment: if the C program is under your control, avoid having it ask for input. Pass everything in parameters, or write to a file before and have the C program read that file (PHP has functions to create practically unique names for temporary files).